# Accessing Rest actions in Custom Rake Task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, automation, rake

I have a small blogging app running in Rails 4.1. It lets a user log in and then create, edit, and delete basic posts with a title and body. It all runs though the user interface perfectly.

I'm trying to write a custom rake task (that will later be attached to a chron job) to automatically create posts. Right now I have this:

```
namespace :blog do
 desc "Automatically post to all users accounts"
 task auto_post: :environment do

   post_title = "Automated Blog Post Title"
   post_body = "Hello World!"

   Post.create!({:title => post_title,
             :body => post_body})

  end
end
```

As best I know it's properly namespaced, etc. and can be run using `rake blog:auto_post`. The controller for Post looks like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = current_user.posts
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new post_params
    if @post.save
      current_user.posts << @post
      flash[:notice] = "New post created!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
  end

.....

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

As I understand it, I should be able to pass my `:title` and `:body` to the `Post.new` action and have it work. I suspect that I'm not interacting with strong parameters properly. Can anyone help clear this up for me.

EDIT: My psql shows the posts hitting the database so I'm close. Not sure why they're not appearing in the app interface though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post.new creates a new object but does not persist it to the database. You need to use Post.create!({:title => post_title, :body => post_body}) instead.

Rake tasks do not call the controller and strong parameters don't come into the picture in a rake task which is run locally. They are there to protect your app from the big, bad Internets.

Comment: This seems like a step in the right direction, for sure. I've been out of practice and had changed to `.new` at some point earlier. This still doesn't seem to do anything though. I run the task from terminal, it sits for a second or two, and then outputs nothing either in the console or the actual app. Thoughts?

Comment: Scratch all this. You've been very helpful. They're not showing up in the UI because they don't have a `user_id` which is an entirely different programming problem.